# I can't understand casting interface to children that don't have any parents

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, casting

I am studying lambda and then WebClient Class
so I am creating bean of WebClient

```
ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder().build();
    
exchangeStrategies.messageWriters() 
                      .stream()
                      .filter(LoggingCodecSupport.class::isInstance)
                      .forEach(writer -> ((LoggingCodecSupport)writer).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true));
```

I think top codes and bottom codes are the same

```
    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder().build();
    
    exchangeStrategies.messageWriters()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(new Predicate<HttpMessageWriter>() {
                          public boolean test(HttpMessageWriter t) {
                              return LoggingCodecSupport.class.isInstance(t);
                          };
                      })
                      .forEach(new Consumer<HttpMessageWriter>() {
                            public void accept(HttpMessageWriter t) {
                                ((LoggingCodecSupport)t).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
                            };
                      });
```

I don't understand this cast situation because HttpMessageWriter is interface
and LoggingCodecSupport is class but LoggingCodecSupport doesn't implement HttpMessageWriter, so I think HttpMessageWriter can't cast to LoggingCodecSupport

```
.forEach(new Consumer<HttpMessageWriter>() {
        public void accept(HttpMessageWriter t) {
                ((LoggingCodecSupport)t).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
        };
});
```

This is the code of HttpMessageWriter

```
public interface HttpMessageWriter<T> {
         ....
}
```

This is the code of LoggingCodecSupport

```
public class LoggingCodecSupport {
            ....
}
```

I tried to test this situation but it makes java.lang.ClassCastException

```
public class Test4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Parent parent = new Parent() {};
      ((Child)parent).foo();
    
   }
}

class Child{
   public void foo() {
      System.out.println("foo");
   }
}

interface Parent{

}
```

Help me to understand this thing

and make this code but it makes java.lang.ClassCastException,too

```
public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent() {};
        ((Child)parent).foo();
    
    }
}

class Child{
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

interface Parent{

}

class bar extends Child implements Parent{

}
```

Comment: Dude - you need some class (e.g. "Child") that actually IMPLEMENTS your interface!  Furthermore, you can't cast "Parent" to "Child" unless Parent actually *IS* a child.  Two "is a" relationships might be "parent subclasses child" or "parent implements child".  I suspect you probably want the reverse...

Comment: Thank you your commnets i understand your contents but  i don't understand this code 
public void accept(HttpMessageWriter t) {
                ((LoggingCodecSupport)t).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
        };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest Spring, this is because one of the subclasses from LoggingCodecSupport implements
the HttpMessageWriter interface.

You can take a look at this class [FormHttpMessageWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/FormHttpMessageWriter.html)

It extends LoggingCodecSupport but implements a HttpMessageWriter interface. That's why it can be cast without throwing an exception.

The example should be like this

```
public class Test4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent bar = new Bar() {};
    ((Child)bar).foo();
  }
}

class Child {
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo");
  }
}

interface Parent {

}

class Bar extends Child implements Parent {

}
```

we can assume HttpMessageWriter is the Parent interface, the LoggingCodecSupport is the Child class, and the FormHttpMessageWriter is the Bar class.

Comment: Thank you your comment. i am known by you
 then,Is that formhttpmessagewriter's existence make to cast HttpMessageWriter to LoggingCodeSupport  technique of spring?
 i try to make samle Class foo that is implement Parent and extend Child and then 
 i casted ((Child)parent).foo(); but it makes java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: In your example, Parent didn't extends the class Child. You should try creating 3 classes. it's like what @paulsm4 said actually. You need to create an example class that implements Parent interface and extends the Child class.

Comment: [You need to create an example class that implements Parent interface and extends the Child class.] I add code through your advice and Edit my questions

Comment: Then you can try that class in the main method. Try  Parent bar = new Bar(); and cast it into Child class, it's the same case for the question. (I used Bar because you should capitalize your class name for clarity)